# How can Select date(dd/mm/yyyy) in ascending order in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I want To Select stockDate in ASC Order My `Table` Structure is.:-

[image]

Comment: change DESC to ASC :p

Comment: Use a proper date type

Comment: Not Possible in month wise

Comment: I don't think this question deserves downvotes. It is well-written, explains the problem, has the table information and what OP has tried. The fact that they made a bad design choice for the DB is something where the community can teach. :) +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have saved the dates as varchar and they are evil, you should use mysql native date data types.

For this you first need to convert the varchar dates to real date using `str_to_date` function while doing the sorting, here how it works

```
mysql> select str_to_date('31/07/2015','%d/%m/%Y') as d ;
+------------+
| d          |
+------------+
| 2015-07-31 |
+------------+
```

So the query becomes

```
SELECT * from inventory_details 
ORDER BY str_to_date(stockDate,'%d/%m/%Y') desc
```

Comment: Thank you Abhik Chakraborty For Help me.

Comment: I want to Select Date With Some Condition Like.,,,                                                              SELECT * from inventory_details where  stockDate >='01/07/2015' AND stockDate <='01/08/2015' Group By stockDate ORDER BY str_to_date(stockDate,'%d/%m/%Y') ASC

Comment: You need to use `str_to_date` in the where condition as well and better to have the input dates as `Y-m-d` format.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * from inventory_details 
ORDER BY str_to_date(stockDate,'%d/%m/%Y') desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the date format to YYYY-MM-DD

```
SELECT * from inventory_details ORDER BY stockDate ASC;
```

Comment: Well, yes, that would work if the OP fixed everything else first.

Comment: As the other answers explain, the data type and format of `stockDate` prevents actual meaningful sorting.