# Inserting data with PHP from a form to MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have created a HTML form which will need to insert the data that was entered into the form straight into a table in mySQL.

**newuser.php file**

```
    <?php
//including the connection page
include('./DB_Connect.php');

//get an instance
$db = new Connection();

//connect to database
$db->connect();

  //fetch username and password
  $usertype =  $_POST['userType'];
  $firstname =  $_POST['firstName'];
  $lastname =  $_POST['lastName'];
  $username =  $_POST['userName'];
  $password =  $_POST['password'];
  $address1 =  $_POST['add1'];
  $address2 =  $_POST['add2'];



  //write the sql statement
  $query = "INSERT INTO USERS (usertype, fname, lname, username, password, add1, add2)
  VALUES ('$usertype', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$password', '$address1', '$address2')";




mysql_query($query,$db);



if (($query) == TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
   header("Location: login.php", true);
   exit();
}
 else
{
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   header("Location: register.php", true);
 exit();
}



  //close once finished to free up resources
  $db->close();


?>
```

**With the following html form:**

```
    <form action="newuser.php" method="POST" class="form" id="registerForm">
        <label> Type of user: </label> <br>
        <input type="radio" name="userType"  id="itemSeeker">Item Seeker    </input>
        <input type="radio" name="userType"  id="itemDonor">Item Donor </input>
        <input type="radio" name="userType"  id="peopleSeeker">People Seeker </input>
        <input type="radio" name="userType"  id="peopleDonor">People Donor </input>
        <br>
        <br>



        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name: "  align="center" class="form-control" ></input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name: "  align="center" class="form-control" ></input>
            </div>
        </div>
<br>

        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address: "align="center" class="form-control" ></input>
    <br>



    <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username: " align="center" class="form-control" ></input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password: " align="center" class="form-control" ></input>
            </div>
    </div>
    <br>

  <!-- <label> Address 1: </label>-->
        <input type="text" name="add1" placeholder="Address 1: " align="center" class="form-control" ></input>
  <!-- <label> Address 2: </label>-->
        <input type="text" name="add2" placeholder="Address 2: " align="center" class="form-control" ></input>
        <br>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submitReg" type="submit">Submit</button><br>
  <br>
  <a href="login.php" >Already have an account?</a>

</form>
```

**The USERS table**

[image: my table in SQL]

The above two blocks of code and the code that I'm working with.

My problem here is, when the form is submitted, the data isn't actually being entered into the table. Note that the first ever submission actually did work. All submissions after the first one don't seem to be entering anything into the database.

I'm not quite sure what's wrong with my code for it to not work. It does go to the 'login.php' page which means there aren't any faults and the query submitted correctly.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, thank you.

Comment: Use `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to check error in page

Comment: Please share the view of the table of db..

Comment: Check this condition `if (($query) == TRUE) {` I think `$query` is `INSERT INTO..`

Comment: Can u provide screen of database table.

Comment: As far as I can see then you aren't actually checking the status / success of the query, right now you are checking whether the `$query` is true, which it is, because it contains data. - I figure you'll see a error if you check the status of the query execution instead.

Comment: @AnshuPratapYadav How can I do that exactly?

Comment: @Epodax Thanks. I thought the code I had was correct. I actually don't know what else I could use to check the query. How could I do this exactly? Appreciate your help sir.

Comment: view for screen reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850993/

Comment: @AnshuPratapYadav I have edited my post with a picture of my table.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php should give you an idea, as mentioned on the linked page, mysql is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: check exact error using mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

right now you have alot more trouble than your insert problem. your code is totaly insecure. (mysql injections).

**Dont use mysql_* functions use pdo instead with prepared statements!**

you output spaces before you send a header you cant send header if you have output. your redirect wouldnt work. dont relay on a clientside redirect use may have it disabled so output a link where you want the user to go.

anotherthing your radio buttons have no value check html syntax
var_dump($_POST) and check if you submit everything. also check for isset or empty befor assign variables. do some sort of validation.

have a look at some php frameworks they provide much more flexibility and error checking

dont reinvent the wheel by writing everthing by your own in a 10 or more year behind procedural way